# Firebase invites deprecated. Set up a user invitation system with vue.js and firebase?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Since firebase deprecated firebase invites, what is the best way to **create a secure invitation system with vue + firebase**?

On top of the firebase authentication, let us assume we have 2 firestore tables:

- `users` containing user ids and project-specific data
- `projects`, where each collection contains project specific data and a role map, mapping a firebase user id to its permissions eg. `{"rf276ft87gsa7vgwv":"owner"}`

We can then setup rules in firestore so that only authenticated users that have the right roles in dictionary can read / write a given document in the `projects` collection.

It seems to me though that there is no way to implement an invitation system securely, assuming the constraint that everything runs client side. In particular, a new user would have to be inserted into the `projects` table, which means that any signed in user would have edit rights on any project.

The only option I see seems like a workaround: As a logged in project owner, use fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() to create an account for an email to invite, then use password recovery.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the *Migrating from Firebase Invites to Dynamic Links with Custom Sharing* [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation), although invites will be discontinued, you can still use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) that was in fact what really powered Invites:

> Firebase Invites is deprecated. On January 24th, 2020, we will discontinue support for Firebase Invites. You will be able to use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) with a custom sharing solution.

So the only thing left to do to rebuild Invites would be to build a custom [sharing solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation#build_a_sharing_solution), there's an example on how to perform it on the link:

> Something similar to the following example should work here (recommending that you use constant string resources in your own code):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's a new lesson for" +
        " learning more Miwok vocabulary:\n\n" + dynamicLink);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Let's Learn Miwok!");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
        getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

And more examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send).

Comment: From the docs, I understand this to be a good answer for Android. What about vue.js apps though?

Comment: The answer was not just intended for android, the example of how to create a custom sharing is indeed for android but on vuejs you can share it through your website, the usage of **Dynamic Links** which powered _Firebase Invites_ was what I wanted to highlight. For vuejs you can create your Dynamic Links either from the Console, the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)  or [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) by sending the parameters and just share it on your website